# Performing Kriging in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, statistics, kriging

Does anyone know how to perform kriging in QGIS? and not via SAGA but actually in the program itself.

Comment: Why should the QGIS developers build a kriging plugin when you can do the same already with SAGA via processing? It will not perform better. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SDA4PP/ was a try, but not maintained any further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The great thing about QGIS is its modular design, based on which you can use the geoprocessing engines of various other systems directly as tools in QGIS (GRASS, SAGA, GDAL, OGR, ...). In order to do so, you need to activate the 'processing' extension. Then you can switch on the 'Geoprocessing Toolbox' via menu 'Processing' > 'Toolbox'. Searching for 'Kringing' herein gives you some tools, you can directly use in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: This Saga Interface do not perform well, because the user can not have access to variogram. In this case, Saga must be opened as well. Moreover, the variogram models available on Saga are not routenely used on spatial dependency analisys. QGIS developers could find a better way to rigorous perform kriging.

Answer (score 2):

With the [Smart-Map](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Smart_Map/) Plugin you can fit semi-variograms and perform ordinary kriging.

- [Video in English](https://youtu.be/-Vv1cAhiSVk)
- [Video in Portuguese with English and Spanish subtitles](https://youtu.be/dzDDNxnwVkI)
- [GitHub page](https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin)