# Interpolating weather data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, interpolation, weather

I am trying to find a proper way to interpolate weather data and use it for regions without the data.

[image: Weather data]

The black points are the weather stations that give me the weather data, the red points are the locations where I have to use the weather data.

How can I interpolate the weather data and combine the weather data with the locations where I need to do further processing using QGIS?

Comment: You need a rather complex weather model, and should include additional data points from surrounding stations.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know which aspects of weather you're talking about.

Comment: @Erik , the Average temperature of the day, and the amount of snowfall are the information in the weather stations. This has to be used to the locations in which I am interested of.

Comment: I think for average temperatur such a small scale is irrelevant. If you need to do it, you could just go for a mean weighted by the distance or so. Differences on this scale will mainly be influenced by micro-climatic conditions (e.g. parks, large water bodies etc. so if you wnat to do it properly you would need MUCH more information).

Comment: @Vincé, What could be the additional information need? So that I can look for that.

Comment: Honestly, I am no expert on regional climate data, I just know that the average measurements will basically be almost the same, especially if you look at climate, not weather. You would need some locally adapted climate model, which (I suppose) is out of scope.
Either go for the weighted average, or try some other sources, such as Worldclim: https://worldclim.org/ or maybe the German weather-service has some data, too https://www.dwd.de/EN/climate_environment/cdc/cdc_node_en.html

Comment: Hi @Vicky, if this answer solved your issue, accepting it as the right answer will help other's to finde help here, if they have the same issue. Otherwise, if you were after something different, it would also help to clearify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small area the differences between the observation-points and the points where you need a measurement are likely very small and the error between a measuring station and any other point within this parameter is small, too.

Maybe the easiest solution for you would be to use the **Kriging-tools** from **SAGA**. These are integrated in QGIS and can be found in the QGIS processing/toolbox/SAGA/Raster Creation. For example the `Ordinary kriging` or the `Simple kriging`.

If you want to go more advanced there's also an experimental **Plug-In** `Smart-Map` which is explained here a bit:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402087/176374